# adobe flex button change style by actionscript

Tags: actionscript-3

I have a button to which I have applied stylesheet(below) which works great.

.toolButton
{
     up-skin    :Embed(source='resources/angle.png');
     over-skin  :Embed(source='resources/angleH.png');
     down-skin  :Embed(source='resources/angle.png');
}

Now, I have a new requirement where I need to keep the button in pressed(down) state until the user clicks on this button again. What is the best way I can achieve this.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use ToggleButton. There is an example at [Flex Examples](http://blog.flexexamples.com/category/spark/togglebutton-spark/).

For Flex 3 I suppose a [ToggleButtonBar](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/ToggleButtonBar.html) with a single button in it would do.

Comment: Hello Vladimir,

    I am still using Flex 3, is there a solution for Flex 3 also.

thank you

Comment: @firemonkey - I think you could utilize the ToggleButtonBar with one button.

Comment: In flex 3 you can just use mx.controls.Button and set its 'toggle' property to true.  You can then style with 'selected-up-skin', 'selected-over-skin', and so on.